# I'd like to add a pause to a linux service, why doesn't my test work?

Tags: init.d

I'd like to make mythtv-backend pause before starting, I tried editing /etc/init.d/mythtv-backend, adding a line at start of the file

```
echo "sleeping 100" >> /tmp/sleep_test
sleep 100
```

It never creates this file, and never sleeps before starting the service. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Systemd does not use the init.d file if a .service file for them exists elsewhere. Please edit your question to include the name of the service, and (if possible) the name of the package providing the service.

Comment: That's interesting, I edited /etc/systemd/system/mythtv-backend.service and added ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10 which did indeed pause the service start by 10 seconds. Not sure why the other startup file is there but this one does indeed seem to be controlling the service.